# How to find a string inside a entire database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, select

I have one specific string, such as "123abcd" for example but I don't know the name of the table or even the name of the column inside the table on my SQL Server Database. I want to find it with a select and show all columns of the related string, so I was wondering something like:

```
select * from Database.dbo.* where * like  '%123abcd%'
```

For obvious reasons it doens't work, but there is a simple way to create a select statement to do something like this?

Comment: Why don't you ask the system developers or the DBA where to find it? It's things like this that have the developers and DBAs at odds ;)

Comment: How big is the database? Is performance an issue?

Comment: 3GB database, no problem with performance.

Comment: You're going to have to write some really yucky dynamic SQL and query the system catalog (`sys.schemas`, `sys.tables`, `sys.columns`) to do this.

Comment: This functionality was available in phpmyadmin with MySQL! Ah the pains..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will work:

```
DECLARE @MyValue NVarChar(4000) = 'something';

SELECT S.name SchemaName, T.name TableName
INTO #T
FROM sys.schemas S INNER JOIN
     sys.tables T ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id;

WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #T)) BEGIN
  DECLARE @SQL NVarChar(4000) = 'SELECT * FROM $$TableName WHERE (0 = 1) ';
  DECLARE @TableName NVarChar(1000) = (
    SELECT TOP 1 SchemaName + '.' + TableName FROM #T
  );
  SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '$$TableName', @TableName);

  DECLARE @Cols NVarChar(4000) = '';

  SELECT
    @Cols = COALESCE(@Cols + 'OR CONVERT(NVarChar(4000), ', '') + C.name + ') = CONVERT(NVarChar(4000), ''$$MyValue'') '
  FROM sys.columns C
  WHERE C.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName);

  SELECT @Cols = REPLACE(@Cols, '$$MyValue', @MyValue);
  SELECT @SQL = @SQL + @Cols;

  EXECUTE(@SQL);

  DELETE FROM #T
  WHERE SchemaName + '.' + TableName = @TableName;
END;

DROP TABLE #T;
```

A couple caveats, though. First, **this is outrageously slow and non-optimized**. All values are being converted to `nvarchar` simply so that they can be compared without error.  You may run into problems with values like `datetime` not converting as expected and therefore not being matched when they should be (false negatives).

The `WHERE (0 = 1)` is there to make building the `OR` clause easier. If there are not matches you won't get any rows back.

Answer (score 14):

Here are couple more free tools that can be used for this. Both work as SSMS addins.

[ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) – 100% free - searches both schema and data in tables. Has couple more useful options such as dependency tracking…

[SSMS Tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) – free for all versions except SQL 2012 – doesn’t look as advanced as previous one but has a lot of other cool features.

Comment: Can confirm, ApexSQL saved me and it is up to date, connected with latest SQL Server and Visual Studio.

Comment: ApexSQL starts at SMSS 2012, so for 2008 R2 I had to use SMSS Tools Pack, but this worked for me.

Comment: If you prefer/need a command-line tool, I wrote an open-source one here: https://github.com/nzbart/sqlgrep

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to options:

1. Build a dynamic SQL using `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` to perform the search ([example here](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Get_Records_from_ANY_table_in_a_Database_Matching_Specified_Value)).
2. Use any program that have this function. An example of this is [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) (free).

Answer (score 4):

```
create procedure usp_find_string(@string as varchar(1000))
as
begin
declare @mincounter as int
declare @maxcounter as int
declare @stmtquery as varchar(1000)
set @stmtquery=''
create table #tmp(tablename varchar(128),columnname varchar(128),rowid int identity)
create table #tablelist(tablename varchar(128),columnname varchar(128))
declare @tmp table(name varchar(128))
declare @tablename as varchar(128)
declare @columnname as varchar(128)

insert into #tmp(tablename,columnname)
select a.name,b.name as columnname from sysobjects a
inner join syscolumns b on a.name=object_name(b.id)
where a.type='u'
and b.xtype in(select xtype from systypes
    where name='text' or name='ntext' or name='varchar' or name='nvarchar' or name='char' or name='nchar')
order by a.name

select @maxcounter=max(rowid),@mincounter=min(rowid) from #tmp 
while(@mincounter <= @maxcounter )
begin
 select @tablename=tablename, @columnname=columnname from #tmp where rowid=@mincounter
 set @stmtquery ='select top 1  ' + '[' +@columnname+']' + ' from ' + '['+@tablename+']' + ' where ' + '['+@columnname+']' + ' like ' + '''%' + @string + '%'''
 insert into @tmp(name) exec(@stmtquery)
 if @@rowcount >0
 insert into #tablelist values(@tablename,@columnname)
 set @mincounter=@mincounter +1
end
select * from #tablelist
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In oracle you can use the following sql command to generate the sql commands you need:

```
select 
     "select * "
     " from "||table_name||
     " where "||column_name||" like '%123abcd%' ;" as sql_command
from user_tab_columns
where data_type='VARCHAR2';
```

Answer (score 3):

Common Resource Grep (crgrep) will search for string matches in tables/columns by name or content and supports a number of DBs, including SQLServer, Oracle and others. Full wild-carding and other useful options.

It's opensource (I'm the author).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep/

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `information_Schema.columns` and `information_schema.tables`, although like @yuck said, `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` are shorter to type.

In a loop, concatenate these

```
@sql = @sql + 'select' + column_name + 
' from ' + table_name + 
' where ' + column_name ' like ''%''+value+''%' UNION
```

Then execute the resulting sql.

Comment: I believe the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` stuff is deprecated. Although they do provide some values that the `sys` DMVs don't. One of these is the ordinal position of a column in a table. I've had to rely on the old views for that a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy and convenient cursor based solution

```
DECLARE
@search_string  VARCHAR(100),
@table_name     SYSNAME,
@table_id       INT,
@column_name    SYSNAME,
@sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)

SET @search_string = 'StringtoSearch'

DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name, object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE  type = 'U'

OPEN tables_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = @table_id 
        AND system_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239)

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE [' + @column_name + '] 
            LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'') PRINT ''' + @table_name + ', ' + @column_name + ''''

            EXECUTE(@sql_string)

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
        END

    CLOSE columns_cur

DEALLOCATE columns_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id
END

CLOSE tables_cur
DEALLOCATE tables_cur
```